# self-hosted gitlab push requires username and password but ssh -T works fine

Tags: git, docker, github, gitlab

I run gitlab in my server with its docker image `gitlab/gitlab-ce` and I cannot push file to neither public, nor private repos.

But I can `ssh` to my git server and works:

```
root@saeed:/home/node# ssh -T git@git.mydomain.ir -p2222
Welcome to GitLab, @root!
```

But when I try to `push` with the following commands, it asks for user `git`, while I added my ssh key which shows I can ssh to my git server:

```
root@saeed:/home/node# git init --initial-branch=main; git remote add origin git@git.mydomain.ir:root/public-node.git; git add app.js; git commit -m 'init'; git push -u origin main
git@git.mydomain.ir's password:
```

I also tried with `http` but keeps asking too.

If needed, this is my `docker-compose.yml` file:

```
version: '3.6'
services:
  web:
    image: gitlab/gitlab-ce:latest
    restart: always
    hostname: git
    environment:
      GITLAB_OMNIBUS_CONFIG: |
        external_url 'http://git.mydomain.ir'
      GITLAB_HOST: 'http://git.mydomain.ir'
      GITLAB_ROOT_PASSWORD: 'SomePass'
      EXTERNAL_VALIDATION_SERVICE_TIMEOUT: 600
    ports:
      - '80:80'
      - '443:443'
      - '2222:22'
    volumes:
      - './config:/etc/gitlab'
      - './logs:/var/log/gitlab'
      - './data:/var/opt/gitlab'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `docker-compose.yml` says that GitLab is listening on port 2222, and your `ssh -T` command used that port, but the origin you've defined doesn't refer to that port. Try `git remote set-url origin ssh://git@git.mydomain.ir:2222/root/public-node.git`; that URL format still uses SSH, but on the non-standard port 2222 you've defined.